# phonegap `volumedownbutton` event not fired

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, dom-events

I'm trying this [example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#volumedownbutton) from phonegap API documentation to try and detect volume up and down button press event.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", onVolumeDownKeyDown, false);
        console.log("DeviceReady");
    }

    function onVolumeDownKeyDown() {
        console.log("onVolumeDownKeyDown");
    }

</script>
</head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run it using my iPhone, I only see the first log `DeviceReady` but never the second one when I press the volume button on my iPhone.

Do you know if it's an issue with my phone or it's something missing in my xCode project? (A missing plugin or configuration).

I suspected the application `BiteSMS` as it modifies the Volume Change popup behaviour (it addes "Press to use BiteSMS"), but even after I removed it still nothing.

- iPhone 4 / jailbroken
- iOS 5.0.1
- phonegap 1.8.1

Comment: Sometimes I don't get when DeviceReady is finished and working. Just give a try: function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);onVolumeDownKeyDown();
    }

Comment: @craphunter now i do see my second log but it's only because it's called from the onload function, still volume change not detected :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, what was the situation, when you asked this question (December 6, 2012), but currently (July 2013, PhoneGap 3.0.0), [PhoneGap API documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#volumedownbutton) precisly says, that the `volumedownbutton` event (as good as `volumeupbutton`, `endcallbutton` and `startcallbutton` events) are supported **only** on *BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)*.

So, I'm pretty *not* surprised, that you don't get them fired on iOS / iPhone! :]

I haven't got chance to test my [PhoneGap Bootstrap demo](https://github.com/trejder/pg-demo-bootstrap) application (which includes example handlers for all events fired by PhoneGap) on iOS, but I tested on my Android devices (two with Android 2.x, one with Android 4.2) and none of them supports (fires) these four events. Last two -- `endcallbutton` and `startcallbutton` -- naturally, as most Android-based devices doesn't have start / end call buttons. As for first two -- `volumedownbutton` and `volumeupbutton` event  -- these are also not supported. You can change volume, while you're in your PhoneGap application, and you see system volume bar changing, but PhoneGap application doesn't react at all.